# Convert several levels of factor into 2 in R

Tags: r

I have 197 levels relating to location, I want to simplify this by creating a new variable "INSIDE" which stores 1 when location is a building/home/etc and 0 when location is outside. I have tried grepl() but it gives an error

```
data$Inside<-ifelse(grepl(data$Premise.Description,pattern = c("BUILDING","ROOM","AUTO","BALCONY","BANK","BAR","STORE","CHURCH","COLLEGE","CONDOMINIUM","CENTER","DAY CARE","SCHOOL","HOSPITAL","LIBRARY","PARLOR","OFFICE","MOSQUE","CLUB","PORCH","MALL","WAREHOUSE")),1,0)
```

> Warning message:
>   In grepl(crime_3yr$Premise.Description, pattern = c("BUILDING",  :
>     argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I have tried using lapply() but it did not work too.
I want the output to be like this:

```
BUILDING   1
SHOP       1
Street     0
```

Comment: The pattern argument needs to be a single character, a regex typically. Try `paste`-ing that vector into a single element using `|` as a separator, which means "or" in regex.

Comment: Thanks, as I'm new to R could you show me an example of the code you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Your data.frame:

```
data<-data.frame(Premise.Description= c("BUILDING 1","MY ROOM","AUTO","BALCONY","OTHER"))
```

The solution:

```
toMatch<-c("BUILDING","ROOM","AUTO","BALCONY","BANK","BAR","STORE","CHURCH","COLLEGE","CONDOMINIUM","CENTER","DAY CARE","SCHOOL","HOSPITAL","LIBRARY","PARLOR","OFFICE","MOSQUE","CLUB","PORCH","MALL","WAREHOUSE")
data$Inside<-grepl(paste(toMatch,collapse="|"), data$Premise.Description)
data
  Premise.Description Inside
1          BUILDING 1   TRUE
2             MY ROOM   TRUE
3                AUTO   TRUE
4             BALCONY   TRUE
5               OTHER  FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks, this code works when string exactly matches my data. However, I have records such as "POST OFFICE", "Other OFFICE" so i want to get my data to show that all records that contain the word OFFICE should be set as "Inside". That is why i went for grepl

Comment: Answer changed according to this.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[
grepl(c("BUILDING","ROOM","AUTO","BALCONY","BANK","BAR","STORE","CHURCH","COLLEGE","CONDOMINIUM","CENTER","DAY CARE","SCHOOL","HOSPITAL","LIBRARY","PARLOR","OFFICE","MOSQUE","CLUB","PORCH","MALL","WAREHOUSE"), Premise),
  Inside := TRUE
]
```

Comment: Hi, does this work for partial matches in string or exact matches? Because i have records that say night club, nighttime club, day club. So i want to just match the word club instead of exact string

Answer (score 0):

[grepl](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) takes a regex instead of a list of options, try this:

```
data$Inside<-ifelse(grepl(data$Premise.Description,pattern = "BUILDING|ROOM|AUTO|BALCONY|BANK|BAR|STORE|CHURCH|COLLEGE|CONDOMINIUM|CENTER|DAY CARE|SCHOOL|HOSPITAL|LIBRARY|PARLOR|OFFICE|MOSQUE|CLUB|PORCH|MALL|WAREHOUSE"),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the code similar to what you listed you need to look into regular expressions which is what the *pattern* part of the grepl needs to be.

```
data$Inside<-ifelse(grepl(data$Premise.Description,pattern = "BUILDING|ROOM|AUTO|BALCONY|BANK|BAR|STORE|CHURCH|COLLEGE|CONDOMINIUM|CENTER|DAY CARE|SCHOOL|HOSPITAL|LIBRARY|PARLOR|OFFICE|MOSQUE|CLUB|PORCH|MALL|WAREHOUSE"),1,0)
```